# Silver stripe - CMS - Login username and password

Tags: php, content-management-system, admin, silverstripe

I don't know how to set admin login username and password of silver stripe? can anyone help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These can be configured in your `.env` file (for SilverStripe 4), or in your `_ss_environment.php` (for SilverStripe 3).

### SilverStripe 4

```
# .env
# ...
SS_DEFAULT_ADMIN_USERNAME="myadminusername"
SS_DEFAULT_ADMIN_PASSWORD="myadminpassword"
```

Reference: https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/getting_started/environment_management/

### SilverStripe 3

```
# _ss_environment.php
# ...
define("SS_DEFAULT_ADMIN_USERNAME","myadminusername");
define("SS_DEFAULT_ADMIN_PASSWORD","myadminpassword");
```

Reference: https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/getting_started/environment_management/

Comment: Do we have to configure this everytime whenever we install silverstripe?

Comment: @Akashlal SilverStripe 3 will walk up your directory tree looking for _ss_environment.php, so you can share this file between multiple projects by placing it in a parent directory that houses multiple SilverStripe projects. For SilverStripe 4 I believe you need to configure this for all installations.

Comment: Keep in mind, though, that sharing a default admin/password is something that should only be done in a development environment.